# Reshape wide datafame into a single column

Tags: arrays, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation

I have a very long data frame like:

```
    1   2   3 ... 109
    1   2   3 ... 109
    1   2   3 ... 109
    .   .   . ... ...
   109 109 109... 109
```

and I would like to have everything in one column as described below:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
...
109
```

I try converting the data frame into an numpy array to use:

```
arr_y = np.arange(11881).reshape(11881,1)
```

but it didn't work. It gave me a single vertical column (which is ok) but from 0,1,2,3,4 .. up to 11881 (=109*109).

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas DataFrame do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1,1,1], 'Col2': [2,2,2],'Col3': [3,3,3],'Col109': [109,109,109]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.ravel('F'))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.